# How to set type for special css-property's like variable . Typescript

Tags: css, typescript

I suppose there are already existing answers and I will thank you even if you just paste the link for the existing thread. But anyway.

There are in React when I specify `style` prop I have pretty good autocompletion and validation.
For example [image: Demonstration of css-property's like variable's autocomplete in React]

### What do I want?

I want to implement the same logic for my variable.
For example, in the code below

```js
const position: ProperType = 'staticcc';
```

I want to replace `ProperType` with a really suitable type. After which

1. VScode will underline `position` and told me that there are errors (because `'staticcc'` is an invalid value for CSS position property)
2. VScode will propose autocompletion like in the screenshot above.

I suppose there should be a special library or smth like this with predefined types. I even have googled [csstype](https://github.com/frenic/csstype), it works fine for objects which I suppose to pass as `style` props. But I need not object, I need a special type for special CSS property to assign to the special variable. And don't know-how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) and

```js
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

const position: CSS.Property.Position = 'static'
```